# Android Error Identification

Tags: android

Please identify this error.

```
08-11 12:34:20.757: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.acdroid/.activityclasses.ConditionalPolicyEntry (has extras) } from pid 
08-11 12:34:20.966: DEBUG/dalvikvm(369): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 172K, 51% free 2706K/5511K, external 2116K/2137K, paused  
08-11 12:34:21.276: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(369): Shutting down VM
08-11 12:34:21.276: WARN/dalvikvm(369): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.acdroid/com.acdroid.activityclasses.ConditionalPolicyEntry}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369):     at com.acdroid.activityclasses.ConditionalPolicyEntry.onCreate(ConditionalPolicyEntry.java:41)
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-11 12:34:21.276: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369):     ... 11 more
08-11 12:34:21.296: WARN/ActivityManager(68):   Force finishing activity com.acdroid/.activityclasses.ConditionalPolicyEntry
08-11 12:34:21.317: WARN/ActivityManager(68):   Force finishing activity com.acdroid/.activityclasses.PolicyEntryMain
08-11 12:34:21.823: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{406da960 com.acdroid/.activityclasses.ConditionalPolicyEntry}
08-11 12:34:23.077: INFO/Process(369): Sending signal. PID: 369 SIG: 9
08-11 12:34:23.097: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Process com.acdroid (pid 369) has died.
08-11 12:34:23.119: ERROR/InputDispatcher(68): channel '4073f5d0 com.acdroid/com.acdroid.ACDroid (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
08-11 12:34:23.119: ERROR/InputDispatcher(68): channel '4073f5d0 com.acdroid/com.acdroid.ACDroid (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-11 12:34:23.167: INFO/WindowManager(68): WIN DEATH: Window{4073f5d0 com.acdroid/com.acdroid.ACDroid paused=false}
08-11 12:34:23.227: INFO/WindowManager(68): WIN DEATH: Window{406e93b8 com.acdroid/com.acdroid.activityclasses.PolicyEntryMain paused=true}
08-11 12:34:23.316: ERROR/InputDispatcher(68): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=196, events=0x8
08-11 12:34:24.028: WARN/InputManagerService(68): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 369 uid 10051
08-11 12:34:24.297: INFO/ARMAssembler(68): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001002_00000000 [ 87 ipp] (110 ins) at [0x445ed848:0x445eda00] in 713146 ns
08-11 12:39:05.969: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
08-11 12:44:06.023: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
08-11 12:49:06.076: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
08-11 12:54:06.117: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

In activityA,

```
 final Intent conditionalIntent = new Intent(this,ConditionalPolicyEntry.class);
         btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {

                    conditionalIntent.putExtra("user_id",1);
                    startActivity(conditionalIntent);
                }
            });
```

In activityB,

```
 Bundle extrasFromCondition = getIntent().getExtras();
    myPolicy.setID(extrasFromCondition.getInt("user_id"));  // line 41
```

PS:error is followed through get function of bundle whenever I place // .
Think I can't pass data.

policy class is as follows:

```
public class Policy{
int ID;
int user_type;
public int getID() 
{
    return ID;
}
public void setID(int iD) {
    this.ID = iD;
}

public int getUser_type() {
    return user_type;
}
public void setUser_type(int userType) {
    this.user_type = userType;
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

check at line 41 there is something null:

```
at com.acdroid.activityclasses.ConditionalPolicyEntry.onCreate(ConditionalPolicyEntry.java:41)
```

or if you can show code...

Answer (score 2):

you are getting nullpointer exception please check in the

ConditionalPolicyEntry.onCreate(ConditionalPolicyEntry.java:41)

Comment: Line 41-> extrasFromCondition = getIntent().getExtras(); which capture extras bundle from previous activity... and I've put extras like this  -> conditionalIntent.putExtra("user_id",user_id);

Comment: could you shom me you code more where you set the value and get the value because here may be intent/bundle getting null

Comment: In activityA, I put constant values in bundle and pass via intent to activityB "conditionalIntent.putExtra("user_id",1); startActivity(conditionalIntent);"
In activityB, I use this code to get it back "extrasFromCondition = getIntent().getExtras();"

Comment: if you pass the 1 as integer then you need to type cast to String first and another thing m still not getting any error in this much of code

Answer (score 2):

there is null pointer in your code in file ConditionalPolicyEntry.java at line number 41

```
com.acdroid.activityclasses.ConditionalPolicyEntry.onCreate(ConditionalPolicyEntry.java:41)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
conditionalIntent.putExtra("user_id","1");
startActivity(conditionalIntent);

myPolicy.setID(Integer.parseInt(extrasFromCondition.getString("user_id")));
```

what is myPolicy.if it is a view then method is setId,not setID

Comment: Rasel>>it's just a class like form bean to carry data

Comment: Rasel>> I have added code above. I thought it was putExtras problem, but I am wrong. I can print bundles data with Log.i() above 
myPolicy.setID(...).

Comment: @Rasel let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2353/discussion-between-renegade-and-rasel)

Answer (score 0):

Since you said "I have added code above. I thought it was putExtras problem, but I am wrong. I can print bundles data with Log.i() above myPolicy.setID(...). – "

and the error is in the below line:

```
 myPolicy.setID(extrasFromCondition.getInt("user_id"));  // line 41
```

The only conclusion that can be drawn is the reference myPolicy is null. Where are you allocating myPolicy?